# Why no "Calorimetry" tag?

Tags: discussion

Calorimetry is still one of the most important aspects of experimental physics, despite being boring. A tumbleweed topic

Comment: There really aren't many questions containing the word [*calorimeter*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=calorimeter+is%3Aq), so it's not much of a surprise that [no one has made one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: It does seem pretty specific. Thermodynamics and Enthalpy would seem to cover much of it?

Comment: No. Calorimetry is hard core hardware and experiment oriented.

Comment: "There really aren't many questions containing the word calorimeter". How witty, and illustrates perfectly the ignorance of experimental physics regularly demonstrated here.

Comment: @Jon When I hear the word "calorimetry" in any context other than the classroom where I am teaching, my first thought is the ones used by particle physicists rather than the ones used in compiling thermodynamic tables. There are a great many hard problems associated getting them working well and interpreting the results.

Comment: @dmckee Good point! Too much thermodynamics running around my head.  On the other hand, this points out a possible flaw with the tag - physics writ large has overloaded the name, so one might have to include the thermodynamics or particle physics tags as well to disambiguate it.

Comment: @Jon The historical approach to overloaded by rarely used tags is to *not* make a distinction until someone complains. Though I think that is a matter of laziness rather than affirmative policy. Then maybe [particle-calorimetry] and [thermal-calorimetry] or some such.

Comment: @dmckee - on a Friday afternoon, I'm all for laziness _as_ an affirmative policy...  I'll have to say, though, that I rarely look at the tags anyway, so I'll shut up now!

Comment: @DirkBruere: Sorry that you think that statements of fact are ignorant of something, but it *is* the state of the site. There simply aren't many people asking about the *calorimeters* themselves (which would be the main point of creating a tag), as important as they are to HEP. In regards to experimentalists, it's a chicken-egg thing, we need chickens to get eggs but, at the same time, we need eggs to get chickens.

Answer (score 7):

You [have the privilege to create tags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). If there are questions in the archive which could usefully be grouped together under the heading of "calorimetry," then tag them!

If there are no such questions, then ask them! (and then tag them!)